# Error: Cannot find module './default_plugins/dates' - knwl.js

Tags: node.js

I am using a library called knwl.js and I am having an issue when trying to require the default plugins. My code looks like this:

```
const Knwl = require('knwl.js');

module.exports = (body) => {
  console.log(Knwl);
  let knwlInstance = new Knwl('english');
  knwlInstance.register('dates', require('./default_plugins/dates'));
  knwlInstance.init("This is a string. This was written on the 2nd of June, of 2015.");
  var dates = knwlInstance.get('dates');
  console.log(dates, 'dates');
};
```

And, having installed it as a dev dependency such that I can see it my node_modules, I am getting an error:

Error: Cannot find module './default_plugins/dates'

Answer (score 0):

Ive just been looking into this and I have this solution

```js
knwlInstance.register('dates', require('knwl.js/default_plugins/dates'));
```

But as it says in the documentation of the `knwl.js` the `dates`, `times`, `phones`, `links`, `emails`, `places`. Is that these are loaded by default loading the other way is if you develop your own parser for it.

Answer (score -2):

Change this line of code.

```
knwlInstance.register('dates', require('default_plugins/dates'));
```